# Multiple conditional probabilities in a simple voting model

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, voting-theory

I am struggling with a voting model problem that is set up as follows:

Suppose there is a binary issue where policy $L$ and policy $R$ are equally likely to be optimal. There are three voters who vote for the optimal policy with probability $p = 0.75$. What is the probability that the optimal policy receives 3/2/1/0 votes? If policy $R$ is chosen unanimously, what is the conditional probability that it is the optimal policy? What if $R$ wins with 2 votes?

It seems like the initial voting probabilities should be calculated normally. For example, the probability that the optimal policy wins with three votes is  $ 0.75*0.75*0.75 = .421875$. However, if I compute the probability in that manner then the probabilities for each outcome (3/2/1/0 votes) do not sum to 1, and it seems like they should. I'm not even sure how to approach the conditional probability for the second part of the question.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^3 {3 \choose k} (3/4)^k(1/4)^{3-k} = 1$

Comment: Ah, I forgot that there would be multiple ways to get two or one votes! Thanks for reminding me of that. Even then, I am still struggling with the conditional probability questions.

Comment: To answer the second part, I think it's asking given that R is chosen by everyone, what is the probability that R is the optimal policy which should be 0.5 as L and R are equally likely to be optimal